# Rails Controller Authenticate two separate user models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication

I have a messages controller, so that printers and users can send messages to each other.  I need to Auth both printers and user. Is there a way of doing something like below in the controller?

```
before_action :authenticate_printer! || before_action :authenticate_user!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a third method

```
before_action :authenticate

def authenticate
  authenticate_printer! || authenticate_user!
end
```

Of course, `authenticate_printer!` and `authenticate_user!` must return false on failure, and not raise.